# Android Autocomplete textview setting auto completion false after item being selected

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to implement autocomplete in android using `autoCompleteTextView`, where by every keystroke a server is hit. I am implementing this by `textChangedListener` as below:

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                Log.d("Going to hit", "SERVER with str" + s.toString());
                fetchData(s.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Problem is when data is being fetched and user selects an item, although I am setting autocomplete text to null, by default the selected string is being printed in the `autoCompleteTextView`. As a result the `textChangedListener` is being called again to fetch new data, which is redundant.

Is there any way I can stop `autocompleteTextView` to fill automatically when an item from autocomplete dropdown is selected ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this, but you can do something like this:

```
boolean isSelected;

autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            isSelected = true;
        }
    });
```

In your `addTextChangedListener`

```
autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                Log.d("Going to hit", "SERVER with str" + s.toString());
                if (isSelected) {
                    isSelected = false;
                } else {
                    fetchData(s.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but it does not work. I am seeing something bit strange. The AutoCompleteTextView is filled up with the picked data before the itemClickListener is being executed.